# Меняется шрифт TMenuItem, если запускать Delphi DLL из C++ приложения

Tags: c++, delphi, dll, embarcadero

Есть DLL, написанная на delphi. DLL состоит из:

1. Формы Main, к которой прикреплены TMainMenu и TImageList.
2. Функции InteractEx, через которую создается форма.

   ```
   var MainForm: TMainForm;
   begin

   // Создадим главное окно приложения.
   Application.CreateHandle;

   // Инициализируем приложение.
   Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, MainForm);
   Application.Initialize;

   try
     // Начинаем работу в интерактивном режиме.
     Application.Run;
     Application.RemoveComponent( MainForm );
   finally
     MainForm.Release;
   end;
   ```

Ситуация такая - если TMainMenu.Images присвоить TImageList, при загрузке dll из приложения получается разное поведение, в зависимости от языка, на котором приложение написано. Точнее сказать, меняется вид TMenuItem.

---

Приложение, загружающее dll написано на Delphi:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Приложение, загружающее dll написано на C++:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Загружается одна и та же DLL. Среда Embarcadero RAD studio xe5.

Comment: А вы случаем не забыли установить ручками все параметры? или таки оставили их по умолчанию?

Comment: Владимир Клыков, все оставил как было, ничего не изменял. Подскажите пожалуйста, что вы имеете ввиду.

Comment: Ручками поставьте шрифт(все параметры).

Answer (score 0):

Видимо в С++ приложении отсутствует манифест с прописанной зависимостью от common controls (aka XP style):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <dependency>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" version="6.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="*" publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" language="*"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </dependency>
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges>
                <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"/>
            </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
    </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

Comment: Боюсь что нет, добавил манифест в проект(через настройки проекта, просто закинул в vcproj и через ресурсный файл), жирные шрифты до сих пор присутствуют. Даже попробовал добавить компонент XPManifest на форму. Все равно спасибо большое за ответ.